# Reintegrating a branch (like svn merge --reintegrate) using svnmerge.py

Tags: svn, merge, svn-merge, svn-reintegrate

Since my SVN repository still uses Subversion 1.4, I am using [svnmerge.py](http://www.orcaware.com/svn/wiki/Svnmerge.py) for merge tracking. I have a feature branch kept in sync with trunk (`svnmerge init` after branching, then `svnmerge merge` every now and then).

Now I want to reintegrate the branch back into the trunk (this is the same situation described in [the SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.reintegrate)).

How can I perform the equivalent of `svn merge --reintegrate` using `svnmerge.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to reinitialize merge tracking on the trunk to discover changes in the branch.

```
trunk_working_copy$ svnmerge init BRANCH_URL
```

This should automatically initialize the merge tracking for only the commits after the branch was copied off of trunk.  Run `svnmerge avail` to confirm.  If not you'll need to pass the option `-r1-<REV>` where REV is the revision of the copy.

Then merge from the branch to trunk is just like before (running `svnmerge merge`).

Finally, you'll want to run `svnmerge uninit` on the trunk.  Otherwise, if other users are following trunk, they'll end up merging in your merge-tracking metadata, and this can make using `svnmerge` more complicated and inconvenient.